# How to avoid splitting decimal number into two integers by Razor View?

Tags: decimal, razorengine, asp.net5

From my controller I am returning a Razor View with a model, where in the model there is property: `AllTotalQuotes.SomeItem`

This property is type of `decimal` and has a value: `4.6666M`.

In my Razor View code I am assigning JS variable from my model as follow:

```
<script>
    var jsItem = Model.AllTotalQuotes.SomeItem;
    console.log(@jsItem)
</script>
```

And `SomeItem` property is recognised by the engine as type of `decimal`.

But when I `console.log(@jsItem)` I receive:
`4 6666` instead of `4.6666`.

[image]

Why? And how to change this? Is this about culture settings?

Things I tried:

- `var jsItem = (decimal)Model.AllTotalQuotes.SomeItem`
- `var jsItem = decimal.Parse(Model.AllTotalQuotes.SomeItem.ToString())`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem is fixed with:

`@Model.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`